# Facebook app loading inside of facebook app

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-page

My app is loading a nested version of facebook inside of facebook. Its only doing this when you click on the App Bookmark, or invitation sent to users.

Please see the link, you will see it immediately (look at the header)

http://apps.facebook.com/passparcelapp/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=1_0

I'm racking my brain to figure out why this is happening.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two "fb-root" divs (which will mess things up) and two fb.init()s which will also mess things up.

But the main problem is probably because you also try to load jQuery (as other libraries) twice - once near the bottom of the body, once in the header - this is leading to JavaScript errors that will cause your redirect. The timings of the load will impact the behaviour, which is why you get differences on local and live - and it may randomly change again.

You also have  outside the  that shouldn't be there.

You'll need to seriously tidy the code up first - then it will hopefully just work. But right now, all bets of off!